# How to get the number of nonzero elements row-wise for a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I wanna find the indices of the rows that all have entries smaller than 1e-6 or where the number of nonzero values is less than 3. Something like this would be nice:

```
import numpy as np

prob = np.random.rand(15, 500)
all_zero = np.where(prob.max(1) < 1e-6 | np.nonzero(prob, axis=1) < 3)
```

Comment: So what is your question? You just need to sum the `nonzero`, i.e. `np.nonzero(prob).sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: I don't understand the question either.

Comment: Oops you’re right. I didn’t think of adding up the number of nonzeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to measure the execution times of the solutions proposed so far:
Benchmark data:

```
prob = np.random.rand(10000, 500)
```

#### [@Massifox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57893259/9302488)' solution with list:

```
%%timeit
[i for i, val in enumerate(prob>1e-6)if val.sum() < 3]
# 39.5 ms ± 1.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### [@Massifox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57893259/9302488)' solution only numpy:

```
%%timeit
np.where(np.sum(prob>1e-6, axis=1) < 3)
# 9.92 ms ± 199 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

#### [@a_guest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57892756/9302488)'s solution:

```
%%timeit
all_zero = np.logical_or(prob.max(axis=1) < 1e-6, np.sum(prob != 0, axis=1) < 3)
np.where(all_zero)
# 13.9 ms ± 150 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The most efficient solution seems to be the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.logical_or` and `np.sum` the non-zero values to check which row has fewer than 3 non-zero elements:

```
all_zero = np.logical_or(prob.max(axis=1) < 1e-6, np.sum(prob != 0, axis=1) < 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code returns the list of index of rows with less than 3 values ​​other than 0 (less than 1e-6):

```
[i for i, val in enumerate(prob>1e-6) if val.sum()<3]
```

or using only numpy functions:

```
np.where(np.sum(prob>1e-6, axis=1)<3)
```